# JS Target a class directly above element

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm trying to use jQuery to add/remove a class to an element but I only want to target the '**.content**' class that is directly above the '**.trigger**' essentially making each work independently of each other.

Any ideas on the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance

**HTML**

```
<div class="instance">
    <span class="content showHide">this is hidden</span>
    <a href="#" class="trigger">trigger</a>
</div>


<br />

<div class="instance">
    <span class="content showHide">this is hidden</span>
    <a href="#" class="trigger">trigger</a>
</div>


<br />

<div class="instance">
    <span class="content showHide">this is hidden</span>
    <a href="#" class="trigger">trigger</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">

.showHide{
    display: none;
}

</style>
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function(){

            $('.instance a.trigger').click(function(){
                $('span.content').toggleClass('showHide');
            });
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using **[`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)** that will only target the `.content` element which is a immediately preceding sibling of your `.trigger` element:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.instance a.trigger').click(function(){
        $(this).prev('span.content').toggleClass('showHide');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also use [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/). It will only target everything in the same container

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.instance a.trigger').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('span.content').toggleClass('showHide');
  });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3nmC7/)

This method will allow the `.content` to be anywhere in the container, whether it is before or after the `.trigger`